# Vaadin confirm dialog

Tags: dialog, vaadin7

I need to create a confirm dialog

The only thing that looks doable is proceeding via a modal sub window but this is a hassle for a simple question.

Is there a better way to implement a confirmation dialog ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`ConfirmDialog`](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/confirmdialog) add-on from the [Vaadin Directory](https://vaadin.com/directory).

[image: screenshot of "Please Confirm" dialog box]

You can include a long message.

[image]

See [online demo](http://sami.virtuallypreinstalled.com/confirmdialog/).

Versions of this add-on available for Vaadin 8, Vaadin 7, and Vaadin 6.

Comment: I had trouble running this in Vaadin 8.0.0.beta1.

Comment: Update:  As of today (Jan 5, 2017), this does not work with Vaadin 8.0.0.beta1.

Comment: @Basil Bourque, I am using Vaadin 7.4.0, and I need to use confirm dialog in my code. So what is that I can use? I am using Spring and Mongo, and I am a newbie and I have started using Vaadin since last few days only, so don't have any experience.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NewbieSoftwareEngineer (a) You should use the latest possible version of Vaadin. For version 7, use 7.7.9. But if starting new, go with version 8 unless you absolutely need to support the much older browsers. (b) I do not understand your question. This Answer shows the add-on (plugin) for a handy confirm dialog. Or you can [make your own sub-window](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-sub-window.html). See the [Vaadin Sampler](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/window) demo with Valo theme. Or see older [Reindeer demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme).

Comment: @cbmeeks This [*ConfirmDialog* add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/confirmdialog) does now support Vaadin 8, according to its Directory page.

Comment: Beware the security warning in the [documentation for sub-windows](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-sub-window.html): *Modality of child windows is purely a client-side feature and can be circumvented with client-side attack code. You should not trust in the modality of child windows in security-critical situations such as login windows.*

Comment: @Basil Bourque, actually I am using 'table' and from 8.0 there is no support for that, therefore I am not using the version 8.0.  I tried to use ConfirmDialog add-on but it was throwing an error on **repeat(MESSAGE_1)**.

Comment: @BasilBourque And in version there is also no support for **beanContainer** and **itemClickEvent**.

Comment: @BasilBourque And I just wanted to ask for any alternative through which I can use confirmDialog in my code. I was about to try _own sub-window_ but now I am in two minds.

Comment: @NewbieSoftwareEngineer You should post a new Question for your specifics rather than discuss in comments. Also, the new data model in Vaadin 8 is *much* simpler and easier than the old `Container` approach. And the `Grid` widget replaces the `Table` widget with nearly all its features plus new benefits including use of the simpler data model. .

Comment: @BasilBourque Okay. Thanks.